# D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile - Random file name?

Tags: directx, directx-9

i'm trying to save multiple **.bmp** files with the **D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile** method but unable to solve it, i've tried making random **strings/wstrings** & convert them to **LPCWSTR/LPCSTR**, using **D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileW / D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileA**, but all i get is gibberish.

Any ideas of how to do it?
(My project is in C++, Visual Studio, DirectX June 2010)

Comment: show the code you have, and we might be able to tell you what's wrong with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, if anyone wants it (used **char** instead):

```
        static int fileIndex = 0;
        char fileName[20] = "capture";
        sprintf_s(fileName, sizeof(fileName), "%s%d.jpg", fileName, fileIndex);
        //sprintf(fileName, "%s%d.jpg", fileName, fileIndex);

        size_t size = strlen(fileName) + 1;
        wchar_t* wFileName = new wchar_t[size];

        size_t outSize;
        mbstowcs_s(&outSize, wFileName, size, fileName, size - 1);
        //mbstowcs( wFileName, fileName, size - 1);
        LPWSTR ptr = wFileName;

        D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile(ptr, D3DXIFF_JPG, p, nullptr, nullptr);

        fileIndex++;
```